# Flutter firebase dynamic links customise link with custom params when handling url on the app

Tags: flutter, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

We had a requirement at a task to handle custom params for flutter firebase dynamic links ver 4.3.7 (after breaking changes from previous version).

Challenge: flutter firebase dynamic links documentation does not have anything written about this customisation.

Answer (score 0):

Decode your dynamic short link using the below mentioned code. After that, you can use that query parameters according to your requirements.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks dynamicLinks = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;

  PendingDynamicLinkData? pendingDynamicLinkData =
      await dynamicLinks.getDynamicLink(Uri.parse("<YOUR_DYNAMIC_LNK>"));
  if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null &&
      pendingDynamicLinkData.link.hasQuery) {
    final queryParametersAll =
        pendingDynamicLinkData.link.queryParametersAll;
   
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Short Dynamic Link**
https://domain.link/dynamiclinktest <- we found that this one is not customisable. *(if it is please comment bellow).*

**The long Dynamic link is customisable.**

https://domain.link/?link=https://domain.link/&apn=com.domain.app&afl=https://google.com&isi=12345678&ibi=com.domain.app.uat&ifl=https://google.com

In normal case you would edit this link by adding extra params as such **/?actionType=invoiceType&invoiceId=99** and in most cases it will work. But during firebase dynamic link handling this link is processed differently and the additional params are completely ignored.

**Solution:**
Encode & decode url so firebase understands that your passing extra params in the link.

Try:
https://domain.link/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.link%2F%3FinvoiceId%3D99%26actionType%3DinvoiceType&apn=com.domain.app&afl=https://google.com

When handling the dynamic url you will now receive the link with params **actionType** & **invoiceId**.

Now the flutter firebase dynamic links can be customisable as much as you need.

Links can be found on firebase console -> dynamic links -> after creating link & clicking on 'Link details'